# ExtJS4 treepanel change node color

Tags: javascript, json, extjs4, treepanel

I have a treepanel in Extjs4 with some of it's nodes are checked in the json code with "checked: true".

I want to change the color of only the checked nodes from black to another color.

I hope my question is clear and thank you for helping.

Comment: I would look into setting a custom class on ones that have `checked: true`, which has CSS that changes the color of the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ext.tree.View` [`getRowClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.View-method-getRowClass) method for setting your own css class for checked nodes.

In your `treepanel` config you can use something like this:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
        return record.get("checked") ? "row-checked" : "row-unchecked";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer to close the question for future reference.